# nUnit and Azure - How to start Dev Fabric from nUnit

Tags: azure, nunit, tdd, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to create a worker process for Azure and I'd like to test it via nUnit. I need to write a process which connect to storage and uploads data to it. The problem is I can't find any references to how you actually set up the testing framework to start dev fabric etc.

I've created the Work Processor role and then created a testing project, wired up nunit to start and for the project to pick up the test project dll. This all works fine with nUnit opening, I'm able to see the test dll and run the test.

My issue is "How do I get the dev fabric to start up when running the project through nUnit?" I'm presuming that I need to put something into the setup routine within the test project but I can't see what I should put in.

If anyone has any tips, experience etc., links to how to etc. I'd be very grateful. I'm sure that I can't be the first person who want to put Azure projects under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't done this myself, but the DevFabric (compute and store) has a command-line interface.

You would just invoke the commdn from your test stand-up routine and it should be good to go.

**CSrun.exe** is the command, please see MSDN for usage reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433001.aspx

Comment: Thanks Taylor - I've just been investigating this and it looks hopeful. From the Setup method within the tests I've started a process which calls  `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /K  "C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.3\bin\csrun.exe /run:c:\applications\testingAzure\testingAzure " /devfabric:start /devstore:start"` - I think its getting there but may need tweaking further. 
I was hoping that there was a c# command I could call instead of kick starting it from a command window - maybe in next release

Comment: Okay - I think I may have done it. What I've ended up doing is spending the day reading various blogs [link](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-running-and-packaging-windows-azure-applications-from-the-command-line) and [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/2a1e5f31-0af1-44af-8e12-0f4e2f936419)

Comment: @Taylor - I've spent some hours on this and I think you're right -but I hope there is an easier way of doing this. What I have now is within the nUnit setup method is a call to csrun which references the definition file and the configuration file. I pass in a few more parameters ( /devstore:start) and it then kicks off the compute emulator. I ended up reading a few blogs but these ones helped me out [Steve Marxs](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-running-and-packaging-windows-azure-applications-from-the-command-line) and...

Comment: ...continuing on [Manually running a WebRole] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/2a1e5f31-0af1-44af-8e12-0f4e2f936419).  The whole solution does seem messy though and I hope that there is another way of doing this. Thanks again-  Steve

Comment: Yeah, I mean its not "clean" per say and I think the intent is that you should be using the actual cloud once you are onto this phase of testing. (not saying I agree, just how it comes off from MSFT docs).  But thinking about all the devfabric does, it makes sense that it would be a bit challenging.  Right now I can't think of any other way vs cmd or p/invoking csrun.exe.  If I come up with anything I'll let ya know

Comment: For those who want to see the solution employed - have a look at [Esteban Garcia's blog](http://estebanfg.blogspot.com/2010/09/writing-unit-test-cases-that-target.html). This is very similar to the way I implemented.